# Interaction between redirect_to and session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, redirect, session-variables, restful-authentication

I have used restful_authentication to implement a login system and it works fine except that
every couple of weeks I can’t login when I use IE; it works fine when I use other browsers! The problem goes away after a few hours! It seems to me somehow sometimes after logging in, the session variable is not set!

I have the following code for create action in my sessions_controller.rb

```
  def create
    logout_keeping_session!
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])

    if user 
      self.current_user = user
      new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
      handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag

      redirect_to '/sessions/home'
    else
      note_failed_signin
      @login       = params[:login]
      @remember_me = params[:remember_me]

      redirect_to "/sessions/login"
    end
  end
```

Can redirect_to '/sessions/home' cause the problem with the session variable and erase its value?

Comment: what kind of session store you use ?

Comment: The default cookie-based

Comment: I found the problem. IE sometimes does not set the session cookie if its name has an underscore.
In ActionController::Base.session in config/initializers/session_store.rb
the key generated by rails was _projectname_session. Those underscores were the culprit. After removing 
them, IE set the session cookie.
To help others who may face a similar situation, 
this problem manifested every few weeks, not all the time, and disappeared after a few hours. It seems for some people changing the expiration time of cookies fixed the problem
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=625561 , but not for me.